# NHibernate - Inner Join between different sessions (different connections)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nhibernate

two different projects I want INNER JOIN statement to write out.

Include the second session of the results, but I can not get

```
using (ISession session = Con1.OpenSessiongeneral())
{
    using (ISession session1 = Con2.OpenSessionsystem())
    {
        result = (from s in session.Query<AU_SalesTarget>()
              join t in session.Query<AU_Terms>() on s.termId equals t.termId
              join b in session1.Query<Branchs>() on s.branchId equals b.branchId
              select new SalesTarget_Derogate
              {
                  salesTargetId = s.salesTargetId,
                  mounth = t.month,
                  year = t.year,
                  calculateMethod = s.calculateMethod,
                  branchName = b.branchName
              }).Skip(0).Take(50).ToList<SalesTarget_Derogate>();
    }
}
```

list returns null

Comment: Are from diferent servers your connections?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why you get a null list, but you should use a store procedure if your SQL Server instance, support the join between different instances.

If is not supported, the solution is not elegant, you can try to get the data first, then use linq to join them like this:

```
using (ISession session = Con1.OpenSessiongeneral())
{
    result = (from s in session.Query<AU_SalesTarget>()
        join t in session.Query<AU_Terms>() on s.termId equals t.termId
            select new
            {
                 salesTargetId = s.salesTargetId,
                 mounth = t.month,
                 year = t.year,
                 calculateMethod = s.calculateMethod,
                 branchId = s.branchId
            })
        .Skip(0)
        .Take(50)
        .ToList();
}

var branchIds = result.Select(x => x.branchId)
    .List();
Branchs bAlias = null;
IList<Branchs> branches = null;

using (ISession session1 = Con2.OpenSessionsystem())
{
    branches = session1.QueryOver<Branchs>
        .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.branchId).IsIn(branchIds)
        .Select(list => list
             .Select(x => x.branchId).WithAlias(() => bAlias.branchId)
             .Select(x => x.branchName).WithAlias(() => bAlias.branchName)
         )
         .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Branchs>())
        .List<Branchs>();
}

result = result.Join(branches, 
    x => x.branchId, 
    x => x.branchId, 
    (x, y) => new SalesTarget_Derogate
    {
        salesTargetId = x.salesTargetId,
        mounth = x.month,
        year = x.year,
        calculateMethod = x.calculateMethod,
        branchName = y.branchName
    }).ToList();
```